# Insert python variable into prosgresql query

Tags: python, web-applications

I am trying to search my postgresql database using a `python` variable in the WHERE clause but I get the error "column does not exist".

Here is my query:

```
query =  'SELECT * FROM public."Kinase_table" WHERE "KINASE_NAME" = ' + nameFilter + ' '
```

The nameFilter is the variable from the user form.

So if a user was to input AKT1 in the search from, the error I get is:

> Programming error: column "akt1" does not exist
>   LINE 1: ...LECT * FROM public.`"Kinase_table"` WHERE `"KINASE_NAME" = AKT1`

Could anyone please help and tell why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: If you mean PostgreSQL you should fix the spelling errors and add an appropriate tag. Additionally better format SQL query and error message as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well what you're doing is string concatenation. so at the end the string that goes to the DB looks like

```
SELECT * FROM public."Kinase_table" WHERE "KINASE_NAME" = AKT1
```

when you actually want it to be

```
SELECT * FROM public."Kinase_table" WHERE "KINASE_NAME" = 'AKT1'
```

Notice the ' around AKT1. So your python needs to look like

```
query =  'SELECT * FROM public."Kinase_table" WHERE "KINASE_NAME" = \'' + nameFilter + '\''
```

notice the '\' characters which escape the ' character from ending the string.

Comment: @Lydia I don't think this is a good idea though... This way of building sql opens you to SQL injection...